# Different levels of merger in forest latex package

Tags: forest

I have the following example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
        forked edges,
        /tikz/every pin edge/.append style={Latex-, shorten <=2.5pt, darkgray},
        /tikz/every pin/.append style={darkgray, font=\sffamily},
        /tikz/every label/.append style={darkgray, font=\sffamily},
        before typesetting nodes={
            delay={
                where content={}{coordinate}{},
            },
            where n children=0{tier=terminus, label/.process={Ow{content}{right:#1}}, content=}{},
        },
        for tree={
            grow'=0,
            s sep'+=10pt,
            l sep'+=25pt,
        },
        l sep'+=50pt,
        [, !l.edge label={coordinate [pos=0, pin=-135:common ancestor] }, !1.edge label={node [pos=.65, every label, above] {branch}}, !11.edge label={coordinate [pos=0, pin={[pin distance=30pt, align=center]135:single merger}]}
        [ [[6][[5][4]] ] [3]]
        [[2][1]]
        ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

It is possible to have different positions of the merger of {1,2} and {{3},{2,5,6}}? I'm reading now the documentation for the forest package, but haven't found any clue showing how to modify it. A nice outcome would be something like this.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put your fragment into a compilable example document that people can play with.

Comment: In which way should the positions be "different"?

Comment: I added a picture. I would like to change the x position of each merger.

Comment: What will be the use of that? It reminds me of dendograms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom style that shifts the coordinates of the parent anchors of the current level and child anchors of the next level respectively (it might not work properly for relatively large consecutive shifts, though):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\forestset{
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    /tikz/every pin edge/.append style={Latex-, shorten <=2.5pt, darkgray},
    /tikz/every pin/.append style={darkgray, font=\sffamily},
    /tikz/every label/.append style={darkgray, font=\sffamily},
    before typesetting nodes={
        delay={
            where content={}{coordinate}{},
        },
        where n children=0{
            tier=terminus, 
            label/.process={Ow{content}{right:#1}}, 
            content={}
        }{},
    },
    for tree={
        grow'=0,
        s sep'+=10pt,
        l sep'+=25pt,
    },
    shift fork/.style={
        edge path={
            \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
            (!u.parent anchor) 
                -- ++(\forestoption{fork sep},0) 
                |- ([xshift={#1}].child anchor)
            \forestoption{edge label};
        },
        delay={
            for children={
                edge path={
                    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
                    ([xshift={#1}]!u.parent anchor) 
                        -- ++(\forestoption{fork sep},0) 
                        |- (.child anchor)
                    \forestoption{edge label};
                },
            }
        }
    }, 
    [, !l.edge label={coordinate [pos=0, pin=-135:common ancestor]}, 
        !1.edge label={node [pos=.65, every label, above left] {branch}}, 
        !11.edge label={coordinate [pos=0, pin={
            [pin distance=30pt, align=center]135:single merger
        }]}
        [ 
            [, shift fork=15pt 
                [[6][7]]
                [, shift fork=-5pt [5][4]] 
            ] 
            [[3][3]]
        ]
        [, shift fork=-10pt [2][1]]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]